# C++ 6.0 integration with Oracle AQ

Tags: c++, jms, oracle-aq

I hava an old application build on VS 6.0 and I need to make a small integration with Oracle AQ. I was planning on using OCCI but I found out that it no longer supports Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0.

Is there any walk around to imlement this?

Thanks,

Comment: there should not be many issues if you upgrade to a newer visual c++

Comment: I would recommend pure C OCI library rather than OCCI. Some open-source wrappers are better.

Comment: My thoughts would be to use a C layer rather than C++ because with every version of Visual Studio, Microsoft changes the layout of C++ standard libraries which breaks C++ applications compiled with earlier version of compiler.

Comment: OK. Thanks, I think the C layer might be the solution.